# Queue and Process subclass instantiation behavior

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm new to python multiprocess API. I have a custom subclass of `multiprocess.Process()`, lets call it `MyProcess`. Many examples I see define`Queues` in `__main__` and then pass to the `Process` constructor.

In my case, I spawn N `Process` subclasses and 2 `Queue` for each (pre and post process). I'd prefer to put the `Queue` initialization in each subprocess:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class MyProcess(mp.Process) :

def __init__(self,ID) :
    mp.Process.__init__(self)
    self.name = ID
    self.queues = {'pre':mp.Queue(),'post':mp.Queue()}

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    my_proc = MyProcess(ID)
```

Rather than:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

class MyProcess(mp.Process) :

    def __init__(self,ID,queues) :
        mp.Process.__init__(self)
        self.name = ID
        self.queues = queues

if __name__ == "__main__" :

    my_proc = MyProcess(ID,{'pre':mp.Queue(),'post':mp.Queue()})
```

Is this possible or is there a pickle/sync/scope problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some testing, the latter appears to work just fine.